# trying to install fmt on archcraft stop because breaks dependency 'libfmt.so=8-64'

Tags: themes, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

i'm trying to install a [Archcraft theme](https://github.com/archcraft-os/archcraft-wayfire), but when i run the command `sudo pacman -U archcraft-wayfire-1.0-2-any.pkg.tar.zst` it gave me this error:

```
 sudo pacman -U archcraft-wayfire-1.0-2-any.pkg.tar.zst
[sudo] password for rick:
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing fmt (9.1.0-1) breaks dependency 'libfmt.so=8-64' required by mpd
```

How can i fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [fmt](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/fmt/) package by the following command:

```
sudo pacman -S fmt
```